# How to find closed regions delimited by lines defined by 2 points each

Tags: vba, algorithm, geometry, region

Given a series of lines, each with an ID and a the ids of two points that define it, I  would like to find the regions that are delimited by those lines, like Region 1 = Points (1, 2, 3, 4) in the following example:

[image: Example of the proble,]

The points 1,2,5,6 will not form a region obviously.

I solved the problem in a brute force method, by first finding the combinations of all possible 4 points, as follows:

[image: Possible 4 points combinations]

and here is the working solution in VBA:

```
    Option Explicit
''+------------------------------------------------------------------+
''|                                                                  |
''|                                                                  |
''+------------------------------------------------------------------+
Sub Determine_Regions(X() As Integer, L() As Integer)
 Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, k As Integer
 Dim nbRegions As Integer, count As Integer
 Dim LP1 As Integer, LP2 As Integer
 Dim P1 As Integer, P2 As Integer, P3 As Integer, P4 As Integer
Dim nL As Integer: nL = UBound(L) - LBound(L) + 1
Dim R() As Variant
' Cycle through all possible combinations
Dim nr As Integer: nr = UBound(X, 1) - LBound(X, 1) + 1
Dim nc As Integer: nc = UBound(X, 2) - LBound(X, 2) + 1
For i = 1 To nr
 ' the 4 points on that particular combination are:
 P1 = X(i, 1): P2 = X(i, 2): P3 = X(i, 3): P4 = X(i, 4)
  ' do I have 4 distinct lines that use these 4 points?
  count = 0
  For k = 1 To nL
   LP1 = L(k, 2): LP2 = L(k, 3)
   If (LP1 = P1 And LP2 = P2) Or (LP1 = P2 And LP2 = P1) Or _
      (LP1 = P1 And LP2 = P3) Or (LP1 = P3 And LP2 = P1) Or _
      (LP1 = P1 And LP2 = P4) Or (LP1 = P4 And LP2 = P1) Or _
      (LP1 = P2 And LP2 = P3) Or (LP1 = P3 And LP2 = P2) Or _
      (LP1 = P2 And LP2 = P4) Or (LP1 = P4 And LP2 = P2) Or _
      (LP1 = P3 And LP2 = P4) Or (LP1 = P4 And LP2 = P3) Then
    count = count + 1
    Debug.Print count
   End If
  Next k
  If count = 4 Then
   nbRegions = nbRegions + 1

   ' the Transpose operation wraps the Redim Preserve because VBA
   ' will not allow changing the first dimension on a 2D array
   If nbRegions = 1 Then
    ReDim Preserve R(1 To nbRegions, 1 To 4):
   ElseIf nbRegions > 1 Then
    R = Application.Transpose(R)
    ReDim Preserve R(1 To 4, 1 To nbRegions):
    R = Application.Transpose(R)
   End If

   R(nbRegions, 1) = P1: R(nbRegions, 2) = P2:
   R(nbRegions, 3) = P3: R(nbRegions, 4) = P4:
  End If
Next i

Debug.Print "nb of regions = " & nbRegions
End Sub
''+------------------------------------------------------------------+
''|                                                                  |
''|                                                                  |
''+------------------------------------------------------------------+
Sub Test_Determine_Regions()

' Input of all possible combinations of 4 points out of 6 points,
' without repetitions
' Note: In the final program, this would be done automatically
' by another function
Dim X() As Integer: ReDim X(1 To 15, 1 To 4)
X(1, 1) = 1:  X(1, 2) = 2:  X(1, 3) = 3:  X(1, 4) = 4
X(2, 1) = 1:  X(2, 2) = 2:  X(2, 3) = 3:  X(2, 4) = 5
X(3, 1) = 1:  X(3, 2) = 2:  X(3, 3) = 3:  X(3, 4) = 6
X(4, 1) = 1:  X(4, 2) = 2:  X(4, 3) = 4:  X(4, 4) = 5
X(5, 1) = 1:  X(5, 2) = 2:  X(5, 3) = 4:  X(5, 4) = 6
X(6, 1) = 1:  X(6, 2) = 2:  X(6, 3) = 5:  X(6, 4) = 6
X(7, 1) = 1:  X(7, 2) = 3:  X(7, 3) = 4:  X(7, 4) = 5
X(8, 1) = 1:  X(8, 2) = 3:  X(8, 3) = 4:  X(8, 4) = 6
X(9, 1) = 1:  X(9, 2) = 3:  X(9, 3) = 5:  X(9, 4) = 6
X(10, 1) = 1: X(10, 2) = 4: X(10, 3) = 5: X(10, 4) = 6
X(11, 1) = 2: X(11, 2) = 3: X(11, 3) = 4: X(11, 4) = 5
X(12, 1) = 2: X(12, 2) = 3: X(12, 3) = 4: X(12, 4) = 6
X(13, 1) = 2: X(13, 2) = 3: X(13, 3) = 5: X(13, 4) = 6
X(14, 1) = 2: X(14, 2) = 4: X(14, 3) = 5: X(14, 4) = 6
X(15, 1) = 3: X(15, 2) = 4: X(15, 3) = 5: X(15, 4) = 6

' Input of the lines, each with the 2 connected points
Dim L() As Integer: ReDim L(1 To 7, 1 To 3)
' Line ID     Point1        Point 2
L(1, 1) = 1:  L(1, 2) = 1:  L(1, 3) = 2:
L(2, 1) = 2:  L(2, 2) = 2:  L(2, 3) = 3:
L(3, 1) = 3:  L(3, 2) = 3:  L(3, 3) = 4:
L(4, 1) = 4:  L(4, 2) = 4:  L(4, 3) = 1:
L(5, 1) = 5:  L(5, 2) = 3:  L(5, 3) = 5:
L(6, 1) = 6:  L(6, 2) = 5:  L(6, 3) = 6:
L(7, 1) = 7:  L(7, 2) = 4:  L(7, 3) = 6:

Determine_Regions X, L
End Sub
```

That said, I am convinced there are a better way to handle this problem. Any idea on how to improve my code, say for instances I have also triangles, and what algorithms are best suited here?

Answer (score 1):

Your points are graph vertices, lines are graph edges.

You have not defined well, but seem you want to select some cycle basis - perhaps set of **fundamental cycles**.

[Look here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_basis) and choose appropriate algorithm (description involves spanning tree algo).

If your graph always is planar, and you know coordinates of vertices, you can enumerate faces using a kind of traversal - choose top vertex, walk the "leftmost" next neighbor, continue until the first vertex is met. Then choose another vertex (not marked yet) and do the same.